# What's the waiting time after the biometric information is sent to the home office?

Tags: united-kingdom

My biometric information was sent to the home office last saturday. Im applying for EEA family member permit and I wonder how long is the waiting time to obtain it.
Is there any way to check how my permit process is going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the location you are applying from, but the UK offers detailed information on waiting times here (after selecting location, select other non-settlement visas and then EEA family permits):

https://www.gov.uk/visa-processing-times

There isn't a mechanism to inquire about the progress of a visa application.